# SQLite with in-memory and isolation

Tags: c++, sqlite, in-memory, isolation

I want to create an in-memory SQLite DB. I would like to make two connections to this in-memory DB, one to make modifications and the other to read the DB. The modifier connection would open a transaction and continue to make modifications to the DB until a specific event occurs, at which point it would commit the transaction. The other connection would run SELECT queries reading the DB. I do not want the changes that are being made by the modifier connection to be visible to the reader connection until the modifier has committed (the specified event has occurred). I would like to isolate the reader's connection to the writer's connection.

I am writing my application in C++. I have tried opening two connections like the following:

```
int rc1 = sqlite3_open_v2("file:db1?mode=memory", pModifyDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX | SQLITE_OPEN_URI, NULL);
int rc2 = sqlite3_open_v2("file:db1?mode=memory", pReaderDb, SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX | SQLITE_OPEN_URI, NULL);
```

I have created a table, added some rows and committed the transaction to the DB using `'pModifyDb'`. When I try to retrieve the values using the second connection 'pReaderDb' by calling sqlite3_exec(), I receive a return code of 1 (SQLITE_ERROR).

I've tried specifying the URI as `"file:db1?mode=memory&cache=shared"`. I am not sure if the `'cache=shared'` option would preserve isolation anymore. But that did not work either when the reader connection is trying to exec a SELECT query the return code was 6 (SQLITE_LOCKED). Maybe because the shared cache option unified both the connections under the hood?

If I remove the in-memory requirement from the URI, by using `"file:db1"` instead, everything works fine. I do not want to use file-based DB as I require high throughput and the size of the DB won't be very large (~10MB).

So I would like to know how to set up two isolated connections to a single SQLite in-memory DB?

Thanks in advance,
kris

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with an in-memory DB.

You have to use a database file.
To speed it up, put it on a RAM disk (if possible), and disable synchronous writes (`PRAGMA synchronous=off`) in every connection.

To allow a reader and a writer at the same time, you have to put the DB file into [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Comment: Synchronous won't make a difference. If OP wants to read from a database at the same time as another connection is writing to it, it needs to be in WAL journal mode (Which in-memory databases don't support, so, yeah, needs to be a file-backed db).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I don't think I can create a RAM disk (my code is a shipping application and has to run on various platforms and I am not sure how things would pan out).
For now I have cached all the modifing SQL statements and I execute them when the said event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This is seems possible since [version 3.7.13 (2012-06-11)](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_13.html):

> Enabling shared-cache for an in-memory database allows two or more database connections in the same process to have access to the same in-memory database. An in-memory database in shared cache is automatically deleted and memory is reclaimed when the last connection to that database closes.

[Docs](https://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html#shared_cache_and_in_memory_databases)